# Ruby, DelayedJob becoming slow when too many Jobs pending

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

When the table `delayed_jobs` start growing on top of the few hundreds, the performance of the workers starts decreasing exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue several times so I expose my findings for future new-comers to this nightmare.

There are several issues opened into the DelayedJobs project regarding to this issue:

- https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/581
- https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/650

The problem is in the query DelayedJob uses in avery worker run:

```sql
UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_at` = '2014-04-17 22:32:20', `locked_by` = 'host:b38f770a-f3f3-4b2a-8c66-7c8eebdb7fea pid:2' WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-04-17 22:32:20' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-04-17 18:32:20') OR locked_by = 'host:b38f770a-f3f3-4b2a-8c66-7c8eebdb7fea pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

It can take almost 1 second, in my case, for less than 1000 jobs.. and increasing exponentially as more jobs pending.

The only solution I have found is the one exposes in [this blog](https://mrfrosti.com/2016/06/06/delayed-job-performance-tuning/), in a nutshell: *As the problem is the lack of proper index for the initial query, the solution is to split the table in batches*:

```sql
-- stop workers
select max(id) from delayed_jobs; -- -> 10010
create table delayed_jobs_backup like delayed_jobs;
insert into delayed_jobs_backup select * from delayed_jobs where id < 10010;
delete from delayed_jobs where id < 10010;
-- start workers
-- while jobs in delayed_jobs_backup do
  -- wait until the batch have been processed
  insert into delayed_jobs select * from delayed_jobs_backup limit 1000;
  delete from delayed_jobs_backup limit 1000;
-- end
```

Comment: would adding a proper index to the underlying database not resolve this without needing to do the processing above?

Comment: @mcfinnigan looks like it is not that easy, in the mentioned blog post and in the github issues there are plenty of tries to solve this in an elegant way and none of them have worked.

Comment: as a test i added 500,000 jobs to my DB and i dont see any performance issues using postgres, jobs are getting completed in .00x seconds. Is there some particular condition of your jobs that exacerbates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Delayed job is not optimized for very large number of jobs. The longer term solution is to move to something like sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), but for the short term you can use the strategy below to clear your delayed_job queue:

http://aawaara.com/post/61798959791/break-it-down

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.6, adding an index on the `failed_at` column helped considerably.